# How to handle logout now that offline_access is going away?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, offline, facebook-access-token

With the new deprecated offline_access method, how can one have a token that survives logouts?

Basically, I made a plugin that allows WordPress users to publish their posts to Facebook. So when a user makes a post, it auto-publishes.

In testing with the new lack-of-offline_access, it appears that if the user logs out of Facebook, this breaks the connection on the site by invalidating the saved access token.

How can I detect that and refresh the token? Does the user need to go back and do it manually? Or can I properly automate this?

Seems to me like Facebook hasn't fully thought this one through here.

Answer (score 1):

> ...it appears that if the user logs out of Facebook...How can I detect that and refresh the token?

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

> **Handling expired tokens, user password changes, uninstalled apps, and user logout**
>
> Regardless if your app requested the offline_access permission, apps
>   should gracefully handle an expired access tokens in situations where
>   a user changes their password, deauthorizes an app, or logs out. More
>   information on these cases including a simple code solution that leads
>   to a uniform user experience can be found in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/).

This is what you will get if the user logs out of Facebook. From a blog post from May 2011: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

```
{
  "error": {
    "type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating 
      access token: The session is invalid because the 
      user logged out."
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

Otto says in comments:

> You keep saying "your app" but you need to understand that I don't
>   have an App. The user is creating their own app for their own site.
>   It's their app, and having it suddenly unable to do what they want it
>   to do is kinda crap. This is why this feature isn't fully thought out.
>   Basically, you're saying that nobody with a website can ever log out
>   of Facebook or their website will stop being able to publish to
>   Facebook. Not a good design.

Dmcs replies:

> If it's not your app, what do you can how they manage their app. 
>   Stackoverflow is not a place for "what-if" questions.

I'm voting to close this question based on this what-if, and that the answer cannot be answered with facts and that the question would lead to debate.  Stackoverflow is not a place for debate.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of how to refresh the token without the user reauthorizing, nor how to get a token that won't become invalid when the user logs out of Facebook.

Comment: so how many questions do you have?  I answered the one that had the ? mark on it.  "How can I detect that and refresh the token".  It also answers "how to refresh the token without the user reauthorizing" (see the first link...you answer is there).  The answer to getting keep a token alive when a user logs out of facebook is also answered in the first link....you need to read it).

Comment: Except that you didn't say how to refresh the token. I'm sorry, but simply parroting FB's bad explanations isn't answering the question. I am perfectly capable of reading their blog. If that actually had any answers, then I wouldn't have asked here in the first place. The question is the first one in the post: "With the new deprecated offline_access method, how can one have a token that survives logouts?"

Comment: The refreshing of the token is in the first link I posted. It's nearly at the end of the writeup.  `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN `

Comment: That doesn't work unless you have a valid token to begin with. When the token is invalidated due to logout, then will that give you a valid one? More to the point, what prevents this new token from becoming invalid when the user logs out the next time?

Comment: You need to make the 60 day one while the user is logged into your app.  That one should not get deactivated when the user logs out. If the user logs out causes your 60 day to become deactivated, your app can detect that by monitoring for that error I listed in the answer.  If you app sees it, then your app should ask that user to come back to your app to re-authenticate so your app can continue to function on their behalf.  If that user finds your app interesting and useful, then they will come back to re-auth to regain that functionality of your app.

Comment: You keep saying "your app" but you need to understand that I don't have an App. The user is creating their own app for their own site. It's *their* app, and having it suddenly unable to do what they want it to do is kinda crap. This is why this feature isn't fully thought out. Basically, you're saying that nobody with a website can ever log out of Facebook or their website will stop being able to publish to Facebook. Not a good design.

Comment: If it's not your app, what do you can how they manage their app.  Stackoverflow is not a place for "what-if" questions.

Comment: This isn't a what-if question. I'm trying to figure out how to modify my plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Comment: Modify it so on each time the user uses the plugin it pops up the auth dialog so you can get a fresh user access token, problem solved.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of the access token becoming invalid on log out.

Comment: I think you're being thick intentionally and I really don't like it.  The answer to what becomes of an invalid access token is clearly explained above. I'll reiterate it for DMCS.  **YOUR** code **MUST** watch for "_OAuthException_" with message of 
"_Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out_". And handle that message appropriatly. Which is to **STOP** using that token and **GET A NEW ONE** from that user.

Comment: Look, I'm not being intentionally thick. I simply don't understand the answers you're giving in a realistic context. So far, I have gotten that if you extend the access token to 60 days, then it won't expire on logout. Fine. Not sure that's true from my experimentation, but I get it. What I'm trying to understand is: how can I refresh that token without user intervention? If it expires in 60 days, then when I refresh, according to the docs as I'm reading them, I can't refresh it without popping up a new authorization dialog to the user. Right? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: User interaction is key.  Once your 60 day expires for whatever reason (user changes password, user removes auth for app, user logs out, facebook error/bug, etc), the user is required to come back to your app and reauthenticate.  At which time your app can request a new 60 day extended access token.

Comment: How secure is it to put the APP SECRET in the Graph API request?

Comment: https = secure,  http = unsecure